# How to get value from input text which is ng-repeated by Tr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a table and its tr is been ng-repeated. one can also add a new row to it by clicking a button.

Now suppose tr is been repeated 3 times and we add 2 extra rows to it and enter some data. when we click on submit button how can we get the whole data of the table in the controller.

Well i Got the answer for this But My actual scenario is like this
My HTML page is like this

```
    <div ng-repeat="details in Information" >
<!--

 my other stuff

-->

<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>age</th>
          <th>city</th>
          <th>add</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="detail in details.personInfo">
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="detail.name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="detail.age" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="detail.city" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="detail.add" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" ng-click="addnewRow();" /> </td>
        </tr>
    <tbody> 
</table>
<input type="button" ng-click="SaveDetails();" value="SaveDetais"/>

</div>
```

My Controller is :

```
$scope.addnewRow = function(){
    var newRow = "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text' ng-model='detail.name' /></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' ng-model='detail.age' /></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' ng-model='detail.city' /></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' ng-model='detail.add' /></td>"+
        "<td><input type='button' ng-click='addnewRow();' /> </td>"+
        "</tr>";

    $("table tbody").append(newRow);

}


$scope.SaveDetails = function(){
  // how i will get all to data from the input fields her
}
```

Now how can i push the data in it. As when i do

```
$scope.details.personInfo.push({..})
```

it gives me an error "personInfo" not define
Then for this scenario how it should be done

Comment: you `compile` element before adding it

Answer (score 1):

You have a design issue here that becomes most obvious when you make the jQuery call. As a very strong rule of thumb **you should not manipulate the DOM (particularly by call jQuery) in Angular, especially in your controller**.

Your `addnewRow()` function should look like

```
$scope.addnewRow = function(){
    $scope.details.push({})
}
```

Then you don't even need a `saveDetails` function - `details` is automatically updated!

Comment: details will be automatically updated on scope, but you will need a function to save it on the server still, so saveDetails might still be necessary

Comment: @SamJacobs True, but he didnt mention one so Im leaving it out. Either way, the `save` function becomes much easier.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you don't want to do dom manipulation in a controller.

If you want `$scope.SaveDetails` (the convention for non-constructor functions in javascript is camelcase), what I would do is instead of adding markup, I would add a new entry to the `details` array:

```
$scope.addnewRow = function(){
    $scope.details.push({SOMEDETAILOBJECT})
}


$scope.SaveDetails = function(){
  //some sort of ajax update call that sends $scope.details
}
```

Comment: as i want to add a new row, how can i push it into $scope.details or what should i push. pls can you explain as it will help me further

Comment: You should add a javascript object that has the same structure as the objects already on details. So detail objects look like this according to your code sample: 

    {
        name: "name"
        age: 21
        city: "city"
        add: true
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a bit approach.

Function `addnewRow`, instead adding element to DOM should add new detail to your details array and angular will update your table.
Data in your table represent `$scope.details` array so if you want get in in controller just use `$scope.details`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  function detail(name, age, city, add) {
    this.name = name || "";
    this.age = age || "";
    this.city = city || "";
    this.add = add || "";

    return this;
  }

  $scope.details = [{
    name: "ammin",
    age: "16",
    city: "NY",
    add: "true"
  }, {
    name: "joe",
    age: "80",
    city: "CH",
    add: false
  }];

  $scope.addnewRow = function() {

    var newDetai = new detail()
    $scope.details.push(newDetai)

  }

  $scope.save = function() {

    console.log($scope.details);
    $scope.saved = true

  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>age</th>
          <th>city</th>
          <th>add</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="detail in details">
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="detail.name" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="detail.age" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="detail.city" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="detail.add" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" ng-click="addnewRow();" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
    <pre ng-show="saved">Details:{{details| json}}</pre>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine, but when "details" i.e $scope.details variable is not coming directly from controller instead its comming from another ng-repeated value then how can we push the values in it to add new row. Thanks

Comment: @shoaib when you use ng-repeter on your view it is always bind to your model ie: ng-repeat="value in values" is bind to $scope.values so you need to push new value to your $scope.values

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to just get back details from scope ?

```
$scope.SaveDetails = function(){
    $scope.details
}
```

Comment: would this give me the values for the newly added rows also?? as this row were initially not part of the ng-repeat and also "details" is coming from another ng-repeated value

Comment: In the current implementation this would not work because the appended rows are now part of `details`

Comment: Yup, thats correct, adding DOM elements by jQuery is not good idea when using Angular, my bad.

Comment: then is there any way so, that i can get the datas in controller. In ideal scenario how it should be implemented. pls help me